# How to use a search cursor on a joined table in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcpy, attribute-joins

I'm struggling to get a search cursor to work on a joined table view.

I've used search cursors before, but never on data that has been joined.
Arcpy keeps saying that some of my joined fields don't exist.

I used arcpy.ListFields() and sure enough, the fields are there. Some of them look different though. They look like this:

Shapefile1.FID
Shapefile1.name
Shapefile1.LPOLY
source_id
title
author

My search cursor code:

```
searchRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(theJoinedView)

for row in searchRows:
    if row.source_id == None:
        arcpy.AddMessage(row.Shapefile1.FID)
```

It says Shapefile1.FID does not exist, when it should. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to get attribute values using cursors. First, you could use a descriptor with the field name. This is what your code does, where you have `row` followed by a `.` followed by the field name. Second, you can use the [`getValue` method of the `row` class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000008r000000), and pass in the field name as a string.

Although `row.FID` is perfectly valid, `row.Shapefile1.FID` confuses Python, because it thinks you want the `FID` property of the `Shapefile1` property of `row`, when in fact you just want the `Shapefile1.FID` property of `row`. To avoid confusion, you should use `getValue`. So instead of doing this:

```
row.Shapefile1.FID
```

Try this:

```
row.getValue("Shapefile1.FID")
```

Comment: @user1191849 Glad to hear that! Be sure to mark the question as answered (the checkmark button) when you get a chance.